# Why is it not subjunctive?

Tags: grammaticality

In this page of grammar under the link : There are two different forms; one subjunctive, the other indicative.
1- It is important that he **_remember** to reply to the letter at once.
6- It is important to remember that he **thinks**_ things very differently to you.

So why is it not subjunctive in 6? Can you tell me why?
I thought of it and perhaps got understood of it, but I want what to see others may say or suggest...!

Link : [Learn English: Subjunctive](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/subjunctive-0?fbclid=IwAR2RiENjBDTnAmW6hw5_LL88CC0ji36RnzViGio_TJMb7D4Rk0GKtR1e6nQ)

Comment: Please don't say, " it is not a good question " OR send me a hint! as much as you always do it as if it was inherent behavior of you !

Comment: (6) is showing what is the real situation, actuality. He thinks things very differently to you. He regards things very differently from the way you do. Fact. The indicative is the only suitable choice, even with the 'It is important to remember [the fact] that ...' adjuration. // What follows is advanced, but needs saying on ELU. Though the 'mandative subjunctive' _is_ acceptable in (1), equally acceptable are the indicative-instead-of-subjunctive (remembers) and the periphrastic should (should remember), and in fact the last of these is (overall) the most discriminating, disambiguating.

Comment: "Remember" licenses only non-subjunctive clauses as complement, not subjunctive ones, hence "thinks", not "think".